# converting characters in a string to alphabeths

Tags: python, python-3.5

This is phenome.txt

```
!@#$% @#$@ $$^@#$ %#@!
```

here, what I am trying to do is convert this combination of characters into letters
the result should be this in a **list**

```
!@#$%     EX AL HA DO PER
@#$@      AL HA DO AL
$$^@#$    DO DO UP AL HA DO
%#@!      PER HA AL PER
```

This is my code so far

```
replacements = {'!': 'EX ','@':'AL ','#':'HA ','$':'DO ','%':'PER ','^':'UP '}
with open('phenome.txt', mode='r',encoding='utf8') as f:
   for line in f:
       for word in line.split():
           for i in replacements:
                test = word
                word = word.replace(i, replacements[i])
                print  (word)
```

Comment: You have something that doesn't operate in place and don't save the returned value, and your syntax is wrong.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I have changed my syntax . Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I iterated over the replacements instead. Each step, I replaced the current key in the string with the corresponding value.

```
replacements = {'!': 'EX ','@':'AL ','#':'HA ','$':'DO ','%':'PER ','^':'UP '}
text = '! ! @ # ! ! %'

for i in replacements:
    text = text.replace(i, replacements[i])

print(text) #output: EX  EX  AL  HA  EX  EX  PER
```

Comment: I have achieved this result however my problem is I need it in the exact output in the opening post. Also the text is a paragraph of characters . You could use this in your text `!@#$% @#$@ $$^@#$ %#@!` the words (characters combination) are separated by spaces

Answer (score 0):

> the result should be this in a **list**

Basically it has O(n), because it iterates over every letter. Thats because you want a `list` as output.

```
replacements = {'!': 'EX ','@':'AL ','#':'HA ','$':'DO ','%':'PER ','^':'UP '}
with open('phenome.txt', mode='r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    objs = f.read().split()
    for obj in objs:
        output = (obj, [])
        for letter in obj:
            output[1].append(replacements.get(letter))
        print(*output)
```

Output:

```
!@#$% ['EX ', 'AL ', 'HA ', 'DO ', 'PER ']
@#$@ ['AL ', 'HA ', 'DO ', 'AL ']
$$^@#$ ['DO ', 'DO ', 'UP ', 'AL ', 'HA ', 'DO ']
%#@! ['PER ', 'HA ', 'AL ', 'EX ']
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please update your script to remove `[]',` I need it in the exact output as this `!@#$%     EX AL HA DO PER` . Also the first character comes out as `None`

Comment: @choman with all respect, it's not that difficult to accomplish and you can take it from here.

Comment: ```result = ''.join(output)```

Comment: @JohnLeonardo this will raise an error, because second element of tuple is `list` object. and  `join` can handle only `str` objects.